Is there any method to track the user order journey from CRM
I have installed Moengage on my e-commerce Website. Whenever user book an order from the website, I fire specific events in the Moengage. After booking, the order is placed in the CRM and my internal team changes the status of order from placed to dispatched/delivered etc.
Now, when I create the user's funnel, I can only track the user journey till order placed, but, can't track the delivered/dispatched status in funnel.
Is there any way, I can fire delivered/dispatch events from CRM on behalf of user? and track them in my funnel?
I have read the Moengage documentation but didn't found anything helpful.

You can send server-side events from your CRM to MoEngage using this API:https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4413174104852-Create-Event
You can also forward these events to MoEngage using your CRM <> MoEngage Zap (Zapier).
Once available on MoEngage, you can visualize these events (order Dispatched etc.) in User Journey or Funnel.

Thanks for sharing the document. It worked for me.
